# Salesforce DX: getting a bunch of can't specify an external sharing model errors

Tags: salesforcedx

Since we made several changes in our sandbox, I retrieve the data from sandbox' package again this morning and pushed it into a brand new scratch org. And I am getting a series of errors when pushing the code, as below:

> force-app\main\default\objects\UK_Case__c\UK_Case__c.object-meta.xml
>   Can't specify an external sharing model for UK_Case__c

When looking at github history of this file, I don't the the external sharing model has changed much. The changes are actually on that we have enabled feeds and track feed history in that object.

So what might have caused the issue in this case?

Comment: I believe you'll need to enable external sharing first, and I don't think there's a way to do this via config file.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks. That works very well. I don't remember we did the same thing last week. Any changes recently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to some changes that lately happened .Check the below from the product manager on this

[image]

So looks like earlier External Sharing Model was somehow enabled and hence this error was not discovered but now that this is disabled by default you are facing the issues .

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, as of 2018-04-24 you can use `ExternalSharing` in the features section of the scratch org definition file:

`"features": ["ExternalSharing"],`